# How to implement on click in cardview + recycler view with firebase?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have implemented a `cardview` along with a `recyclerview` that fetch data from firebase. I want to implement `onclick` methods to cards that goes for different activities. How can i add on click method for the cards? Here is my mainactivity.

```
 public class English extends AppCompatActivity   {
    ViewHolder apt;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference mRef;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_english);


        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("English");


    }

    private void firebaseSearch(String searchText){
        Query firebaseSearchQuery=mRef.orderByChild("artist").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<englishacti, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<englishacti, ViewHolder>(englishacti.class,R.layout.row,ViewHolder.class,firebaseSearchQuery) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, englishacti model, int position) {
                holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(),model.getAlbum(),model.getDescription(),model.getImage(),model.getArtist());
            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<englishacti,ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<englishacti, ViewHolder>(englishacti.class,R.layout.row,ViewHolder.class,mRef) {
            @Override

            protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, englishacti model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getAlbum(), model.getDescription(), model.getImage(), model.getArtist());



            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                firebaseSearch(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                firebaseSearch(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id=item.getItemId();
        if (id==R.id.action_settings){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }




}
```

Comment: @HelloWorld please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/6296561

Comment: use custom adapter, set onclick listener to the view, or use item click listener on recyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please take a look at my snipshed code, in my case i use this way to implement setonlclick in recycleview item and send value to other activity

```
holder.setName(userName);
                    holder.setUserImage(userThumb, getContext());

                    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), Tampung_chatActivity.class);
                            chatIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                            chatIntent.putExtra("user_name", userName);
                            startActivity(chatIntent);
                        }
                    });
```

full code you can see at here : 
[full snipshed code implement onclick with recycleview and firebase](https://github.com/yudikarma/TanyaDokterHewan/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/jon_snow/tanyadokterhewan/Fragment/ChatFragment.java)